# Eliminate OS/browser-added scroll space

Tags: html, css

In the following code I'd like to see only shades of blue.

I understand that the white space added is under the control of either
the OS or the browser. Still, there must be a way to get rid of it, at
least for the div on the left, where there is no overflow,
but ideally for both the left and right DIVs.

```js
function loremipsum(divclass, number, what) {
    var lorem = document.getElementsByClassName(divclass);
    for(i=0; i<number; i++)
        lorem[0].innerHTML += what;
}
loremipsum("one", 20, "left ");
loremipsum("two", 2000, "right ");
```

```css
body {
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
}
.wrapper{
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.holder {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: grid;

    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 3fr;
    grid-template-areas:"one two";
    background-color: #154360;
}
.box {
    padding: 10px; margin: 10px;
    border: 10px solid #2E86C1;
    background-color: #AED6F1;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    color: #154360;
}
.one  { grid-area: one;  }
.two { grid-area: two; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="holder">
        <div class="box one"></div>
        <div class="box two"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to `.one` or `.box` `overflow-y: hidden;` . now you can't scroll at all. Don't know if that is wanted.